# Existence of minimizer of a strongly convex quadratic function on a closed set?

Tags: optimization

$$
\min\limits_{x\in \mathcal{X}} \|x\|_2^2
$$
where $\mathcal{X}\subseteq R^N$ is a closed set but not necessary convex and can be unbounded. Then existence of optimal solution to this problem holds or not?

Comment: Yes, of course, because $\lVert x\rVert_2^2$ is continuous and it diverges to infinity away from $0$. Not necessarily unique, of course.

Comment: What is the space in which you are working? Is it finite dimensional?

Comment: Thanks for Saucy and Kavi's help. The problem has solved. The objective is coercive on the closed set $\mathcal{X}$. So it attains its minimum on $\mathcal{X}$.